# Trouble converting an SQL query to Eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Trying to get this query to work in eloquent

A user can be in multiple teams however I want to generate a list of users NOT in a specific team. The following SQL query works if executed directly but would like to make it cleaner by converting it to eloquent

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN team_members ON team_members.member_id = users.id WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM team_members WHERE team_members.member_id = users.id AND team_members.team_id = $team_id )
```

This should provide a list of all the users that are not members of team $team_id

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess ad you do not give much info on your Eloqent models but here is a hint of where to go:

```
User::doesnthave('teamMembers', function($builder) use($team_id){
   return $builder->where('team_members.team_id');
});
```

That is assuming you have a "User" model with a "teamMembers" relationship setup on it

You may have a closer look in the [Laravel docs for doesntHave](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence)

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel 5.8**

Let's assume you have model name "User.php"
& there is method name "teamMembers" in it.

Basic

```
$users = User::doesntHave('teamMembers')->get();
```

Advance

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

$users = User::whereDoesntHave('teamMembers', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('id', '=', {your_value});
})->get();
```

You can find details description in this link >>
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

**Laravel 5.2**

Example:

```
DB::table('users')
            ->whereExists(function ($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                      ->from('orders')
                      ->whereRaw('orders.user_id = users.id');
            })
            ->get();
```

Check this link for advance where clause:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses

Answer (score 0):

You can use below example

```
$list = User::leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'team_members.member_id')
             ->whereNotExists(function ($query) use ($team_id) {
             $query->from('team_members')
                   ->whereRaw('team_members.member_id = users.id')
                   ->where('team_members.team_id', '=', $team_id);
              })
            ->get();
```